# Why is my print function not working? Linked list

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am doing a class assignment, where I have to create a linked list representing a big number, but I cant get the print function to work.

This is the code:

Header

```cpp
class List
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node* next;
    };
    node* head;
    node* temp;
    node* curr;
public: 
    List();
    void addNode(std::string digits);
    void printList();
};
```

Constructor

```cpp
List::List()
{
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}
```

Function that creates the list

```cpp
void List::addNode(string digits)
{
    int o = 1;
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    node *n;
    node *head;
    node *temp;
    //=================================================================================//
    n = new node;
    if (digits[0]=='-')
    {
        n -> data = -1;
        head = n;
        temp = n;
    }
    else
    {
        n -> data = 1;
        head = n;
        temp = n;
    }
    //================================================================================//
    if ((head->data) == -1)
    {
        while (o < digits.length())
        {
            n = new node;
            n->data = stoi(digits.substr(o,1));
            temp -> next = n;
            temp = temp -> next;
            o++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(i < digits.length())
        {
            n = new node;
            n->data = stoi(digits.substr(i,1));
            temp -> next = n;
            temp = temp -> next;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

The print function I've been trying to implement, it gives no output (blank):

```cpp
void List::printList()
{
    node* curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        cout<<curr -> data<<" ";
        curr = curr -> next;
    }
}
```

The list prints fine when I use this code in the `addNode` function:

```cpp
if ((head -> data) == -1)
{
    while(j < digits.length())
    {
        cout<<head -> data<<" ";
        head = head -> next;
        j++;
    }
}
else
{
    while(j<=digits.length())
    {
        cout<<head -> data<<" ";
        head = head -> next;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `node *head;` in `List::addNode(string digits)` you are not using the member variable `head` you declare a new local variable `head` that shadows the member variable with the same name and that goes away after the function is done. So the `head` member variable is still `NULL` and your print has nothing to print.

Comment: ***The list prints fine when I use this code in the addNode function*** It should not print at all.

Comment: What I meant by the second comment is if you left the `node *head;` bug in the `addNode()` function you should not print because you don't modify the `head` member.

Answer (score 2):

For starters these data members

```
node* temp;
node* curr;
```

are redundant. Instead of them you can use similar local variables in member functions of the class if it is required.

The function `addNode` deals with the local variable `head` instead of the data member with the same name.

```
void List::addNode(string digits)
{
    int o = 1;
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    node *n;
    node *head;
    //…
```

Also you forgot to set the data member next of the last node to `nullptr`.

If the member function will be called a second time then there will be memory leaks.

Calling the standard function `std::stoi` for one character

```
n->data = stoi(digits.substr(i,1));
```

is inefficient.

The class can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below. You will need to add other required member functions (as for example the copy constructor or destructor) yourself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class List
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node *next;
    } *head = nullptr;
public: 
    List() = default;
    void addNode( const std::string &digits );
    std::ostream & printList( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const;
};


void List::addNode( const std::string &digits )
{
    if ( !digits.empty() && 
         !( digits.size() == 1 && ( digits[0] == '-' || digits[0] == '+') ) )
    {

        node **current = &head;

        while ( *current )
        {
            node *tmp = *current;
            *current = ( *current )->next;
            delete tmp;
        }

        std::string::size_type i = 0;

        *current = new node { digits[i] == '-' ? -1 : 1, nullptr };

        if ( digits[i] == '-' || digits[i] == '+' ) ++i;

        for ( ; i < digits.size(); i++ )
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;

            *current = new node { digits[i] - '0', nullptr };
        }
    }
}

std::ostream & List::printList( std::ostream &os ) const
{
    if ( head != nullptr )
    {
        if ( head->data == -1 ) os << '-'; 

        for ( node *current = head->next; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
        {
            os << current->data;
        }
    }

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    List lst;

    lst.addNode( "-123456789" );
    lst.printList() << '\n';

    lst.addNode( "987654321" );
    lst.printList() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
-123456789
987654321
```

Comment: Future readers: Pay special attention to how much code the `node **current = &head;` trick eliminated.